# Microsoft YaHei is not working properly in SciChart 3D WPF

Tags: wpf, scichart

I am testing SciChart3d for wpf, setting the font on the X axis to Microsoft YaHei, SciChart3d is not working, and the version of SciChart3d is 5.3.0.11954.

```
<s3D:SciChart3DSurface x:Name="SciChart" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="0" WorldDimensions="200,100,200">
        <s3D:SciChart3DSurface.RenderableSeries>
            <s3D:PointLineRenderableSeries3D x:Name="PointLineSeries3D" IsAntialiased="True" StrokeThickness="1">
                <s3D:PointLineRenderableSeries3D.PointMarker>
                    <s3D:SpherePointMarker3D  Size="5"/>
                </s3D:PointLineRenderableSeries3D.PointMarker>
            </s3D:PointLineRenderableSeries3D>
        </s3D:SciChart3DSurface.RenderableSeries>
        <s3D:SciChart3DSurface.XAxis>
            <s3D:NumericAxis3D GrowBy="0.1,0.1" FontFamily="Microsoft YaHei"/>
        </s3D:SciChart3DSurface.XAxis>
        <s3D:SciChart3DSurface.YAxis>
            <s3D:NumericAxis3D GrowBy="0.1,0.1" FontFamily="Microsoft YaHei"/>
        </s3D:SciChart3DSurface.YAxis>
        <s3D:SciChart3DSurface.ZAxis>
            <s3D:NumericAxis3D GrowBy="0.1,0.1" FontFamily="KaiTi"/>
        </s3D:SciChart3DSurface.ZAxis>
    </s3D:SciChart3DSurface>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNE3k.png)

Comment: Thank you for reporting this, I added it to the issue tracker for SciChart https://abtsoftware.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/issue/SC-5233

Answer (score 1):

Support for Chinese, Japanese and extended character sets was added to SciChart WPF 3D in [version 7](https://www.scichart.com/scichart-wpf-v7-0-released/). The release note can be found here:

[scichart.com/scichart-wpf-v7-0-released](https://www.scichart.com/scichart-wpf-v7-0-released/)

> **Improved SciChart 3D Text Rendering**
>
> Under the hood we’ve written a completely new, cross-platform, in-house DirectX text rendering engine. This allows us to draw high quality text with Unicode characters, Cyrillic, Arabic or special characters.
>
> We’ve also added support for **Japanese**, **Chinese** and **Korean** characters to SciChart WPF 3D. This has been long requested but required the intensive rework of our cross-platform text rendering engine.

Here's an image of Microsoft YaHei working with SciChart WPF v7

[image: Microsoft YaHei SciChart WPF]